# Translating get/set from C# to C++, using header files

Tags: c#, c++, class, constructor, header

As preface, I am recreating the bare-bones of an old game project. It was written in C#, and I am doing my best to convert what I had into C++. I am also using Visual Studio Professional 2013. In this instance, I had a Coordinate class that could dynamically get and set values to its X and Y properties. All in all it was fairly straight-forward.

This is the C# class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConquestGameEngine.Map
{

    public class Coordinate
    {
        public int X { get; set; }
        public int Y { get; set; }
        public Coordinate(int x, int y)
        {
            this.X = x;
            this.Y = y;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the C++ class and header:

```
//Coordinate.h
#pragma once
class Coordinate
{
public:
    Coordinate(int x, int y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }
    ~Coordinate();
    int X, Y;
};

//Coodinate.cpp
using namespace std;
#include "Coordinate.h"

Coordinate::Coordinate(int x, int y)
{
    Coordinate::X = x;
    Coordinate::Y = y;
}

Coordinate::~Coordinate()
{
}
```

With my limited knowledge and experience, and the research/studying I've done, I've a fairly good grasp of a header file's function and purpose and how to use them. But the more I try to recreate the get-set principle established in the C#, the more I get confused on whether or not something should go in the .h or the .cpp. I'm also pretty noob-ish when it comes to familiarity with the library and how to use it, so I don't know if there's another way to go about it. None of the exmaples I've been able to find online come close to having my problem, or answering my question, or are largely too generic or specific to help.

There is a secondary issue of a class called TilePattern that is comprised of a list of Coordinates, but I feel like I will be able to solve that on my own once I figure out this Coordinate issue.

So am I overlooking something really simple? Is it a novice mistake? Is this just a much more complicated in C++? Is there a tool in the library that I'm unaware of that could fix all of this?

Comment: Your constructor is already implemented in the header, no need to redefine it in the cpp file. Also, C++ does not have properties, so using preprocessor magic to emulate that behaviour is an ugly hack. 
In this specific cases, keeping X and Y it as a public field/member variable is perfectly OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of, it looks like you are defining the constructor both in the 
header, and then in the cpp. that's one to many. 
Second, if `Coordinate` does not 'react' to changes, what you want is 
probably something like:

```
struct Coordinate {
    int x,y;
};
```

dont over-design it. it can still be used like

```
return Coordinate{5,7} ;
```

and the like. If you actually need getter, setter methods, for reporting the 
change, checking its within bonds etc, yes that's a bit more verbose in C++, 
if you must have assignment syntax, otherwise a common way to do it is:

```
int X() { return x; }
void X(int xx) { x=xx; report_change(); }
```

Comment: The duplicate constructor was a silly mistake. So I've eliminated that from the .cpp now, but it still needs two ints because of how the constructor is defined in the .h . So I'm confused as to how to get and set X and Y values to serve as input for the .cpp that calls the constructor. What you said sorta looks like it'd work, but I'm not sure I understand it... could you explain it just a bit further? Alternatively, what's the name of the thing I can look up to try to find out the answer for myself?

Comment: you don't really need a constructor for such a simple type. check out `uniform initialization`

Answer (score 0):

I have posted a solution on the my site some time ago: http://www.cbuilderblog.com/una-classe-template-alternativa-a-__property/

I proposed an implementation of the get/set properties using a template class.

This is the template class:

```
    // Template class for __property construct emulation
template< typename owner_t, typename prop_t, void (owner_t::*setter)(prop_t), prop_t (owner_t::*getter)() >
class CProperty
{
public:
  // Constructor
  CProperty(owner_t* owner){m_owner = owner;}

  // op = overloading
  void operator=(prop_t value)
  {
    return (m_owner->*setter)(value);
  }
  // op type overloading
  operator prop_t()
  {
    return (m_owner->*getter)();
  }
private:
  owner_t* m_owner;
};
```

end this is an exmple of use in a CPanel class which declares some properties:

```
class CPanel
{
private:
  int m_Width;  // Private member for Width property
  int m_Height; // Private member for Height property

protected:
  void __fastcall SetWidth(int AValue); // Set the Width property  
  int __fastcall  GetWidth();           // Get the Width property

  void __fastcall SetHeight(int AValue);// Set the Height property
  int  __fastcall GetHeight();          // Get the Height property

public:
  CPanel()
  :Width(this), Height(this)
  {
  }

  CProperty<CPanel, int, SetWidth,  GetWidth>  Width;
  CProperty<CPanel, int, SetHeight, GetHeight> Height;
}
```

If you need more help, you can ask on comment section.

Answer (score 0):

Well yes don't over compilable it

I would do something like this

```
//Coordinate.h
class Coordinate
{
private:
   int m_x;
   int m_y;
public:
   Coordinate(const int& x_, const int& y_):m_x(x),m_y(y){}
   Coordinate():m_x(0),m_y(0){}

   const int& x() const;
   void x(const int& x_);

   //For these methods I would do it inline like this.
   const int& y() const {return m_y;}
   void y(const int& y_) {m_y = y_;}
};

//Coordinate.cpp (if used)
const int& Coordinate::x() {return m_x;}
void Coordinate::x(const int& x_) {m_x = x_;}
```

Note that get/set is not used a lot in C++ the C++ way of getting a name is just to say `name()`. Setting a name might warrant a `set_name(const std::string& name)` but I usually prefer the minimalistic `void name(const std::string& name)` it make sense when it is paired with the getter `name()`.

You can also do just

```
class Coordinate
{
...
public:
   int& x(){return m_x;}
...
};
```

and use it as

```
Coordinate c(3,4);
std::cout<<c.x()<<std::endl;
c.x() = 17;
std::cout<<c.x()<<std::endl;
```

Which will print

```
3
17
```

However this last way of doing it exposes internal implementation details of your class and should be avoided.